# Facing org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidPidMappingException in spring kafka

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am using spring boot 2.1.9 with spring Kafka 2.2.9.

My spring boot application was idle from the last 2 weeks, it's running but still, no one accessing the API. But when today I started using, for the first request it gave me below error.

```
2019-12-18 14:43:03.908 ERROR [xxxx-account-service,681c8de32a0d1127,681c8de32a0d1127,false] 10 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Application exception overridden by commit exception

org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Cannot perform send because at least one previous transactional or idempotent request has failed with errors.
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.TransactionManager.failIfNotReadyForSend(TransactionManager.java:279)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.TransactionManager.maybeAddPartitionToTransaction(TransactionManager.java:264)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:862)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:803)
        at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory$CloseSafeProducer.send(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:470)
        at brave.kafka.clients.TracingProducer.send(TracingProducer.java:106)
        at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.doSend(KafkaTemplate.java:407)
        at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.send(KafkaTemplate.java:217)
        at com.xxxx.service.messaging.impl.MessageProducerImpl.sendStringMessage(MessageProducerImpl.java:61)
        at com.xxxx.service.messaging.impl.MessageProducerImpl.sendIntegerMessage(MessageProducerImpl.java:72)
        at com.xxxx.service.messaging.impl.MessageProducerImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$5b6c8aa3.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:295)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
        at com.xxxx.service.messaging.impl.MessageProducerImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9b7897c2.sendIntegerMessage(<generated>)
        at com.xxxx.business.account.service.impl.AccountServiceImpl.messageToCreateAccountInCrm(AccountServiceImpl.java:681)
        at com.xxxx.business.account.service.impl.AccountServiceImpl.create(AccountServiceImpl.java:181)
        at com.xxxx.business.account.service.impl.AccountServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f9aea063.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:295)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
        at com.xxxx.business.account.service.impl.AccountServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e65a7102.create(<generated>)
        at com.xxxx.business.account.controller.AccountController.add(AccountController.java:148)
        at com.xxxx.business.account.controller.AccountController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$433a991.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:69)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
        at com.xxxx.business.account.controller.AccountController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ad6dfe61.add(<generated>)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282)
        at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$LockedScopedProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GenericScope.java:494)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
        at com.xxxx.business.account.controller.AccountController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$364d785d.add(<generated>)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:893)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:798)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:88)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:176)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:94)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.ExceptionLoggingFilter.doFilter(ExceptionLoggingFilter.java:48)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at brave.servlet.TracingFilter.doFilter(TracingFilter.java:86)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:114)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:104)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidPidMappingException: The producer attempted to use a producer id which is not currently assigned to its transactional id
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.TransactionManager$AddPartitionsToTxnHandler.handleResponse(TransactionManager.java:1039)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.TransactionManager$TxnRequestHandler.onComplete(TransactionManager.java:907)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientResponse.onComplete(ClientResponse.java:109)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.completeResponses(NetworkClient.java:532)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:524)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:216)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:163)
        ... 1 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidPidMappingException: The producer attempted to use a producer id which is not currently assigned to its transactional id
```

What this error for? any config issue!

Is the Kafka server will go for the idle state if we not use..?

Answer (score 16):

This issue happened due to the below reasons.

transactional.id.expiration.ms.

The maximum amount of time in ms that the transaction coordinator will wait before proactively expire a producer’s transactional ID without receiving any transaction status updates from it.

Type: int

Default: 604800000

604800000 ms is 7 days. So basically, if we’ve had a streaming application that had no traffic for 7 days, it’s producer metadata was deleted – and that’s the behaviour we’ve been seeing: the application consumed the message, processed it – and when it tried to commit the transaction and update the offset, it failed. This is why we processed, crushed, and re-processed

Answer (score 2):

It's documented in the Spring Kafka docs, even if it's hard to find
https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.8.11/reference/html/#transactions

> Starting with version 2.5.8, you can now configure the maxAge property on the producer factory. This is useful when using transactional producers that might lay idle for the broker’s transactional.id.expiration.ms. With current kafka-clients, this can cause a ProducerFencedException without a rebalance. By setting the maxAge to less than transactional.id.expiration.ms, the factory will refresh the producer if it is past it’s max age.

So you should set maxAge smaller than the broker config value *transactional.id.expiration.ms*

```java
    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, YourEvent> inventoryEventProducerFactory() {
        DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<String, YourEvent> kafkaProducerFactory =
                new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs(), new StringSerializer(), new JsonSerializer<>(
                        new ObjectMapper().registerModules(new JavaTimeModule())
                                .disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)));
        kafkaProducerFactory.setTransactionIdPrefix(transactionIdPrefix + UUID.randomUUID());
       // smaller than transactional.id.expiration.ms. Default: 604800000
        kafkaProducerFactory.setMaxAge(Duration.ofMillis(600000000)); 


        return kafkaProducerFactory;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> The producer attempted to use a producer id which is not currently assigned to its transactional id

It probably means you have two independent producers using the same `transactional.id`.

They have to be unique across application instances for producer-initiated transactions.

Comment: I have only one instance and one producer which is connected to Kafka now. it only happens if the producer is idle for long time (week).  And after 2 or 3 attempts, it again starts working properly. this issue I faced 2nd time in the last 4 months.

Comment: @JoysonRego, did you finally find a solution? I have the same problem, like you, it only happens if the producer is idle for long time (week). And after 2 or 3 attempts, it again starts working properly.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer of @besanur , if you're using a producer factory from Spring auto configuration, it's possible to only create a DefaultKafkaProducerFactoryCustomizer bean instead of creating a producer factory manually.

Below is a Kotlin example of this:

```
@Bean
fun defaultKafkaProducerFactoryCustomizer(): DefaultKafkaProducerFactoryCustomizer {
    return DefaultKafkaProducerFactoryCustomizer { producerFactory -> producerFactory.setMaxAge(Duration.ofDays(1)) }
}
```