# How to correct handle InvalidPidMappingException

Tags: apache-kafka, error-handling

Please tell me how to correctly handle InvalidPidMappingException. What variations are correct - handling the catching of this type of exception in the process processing logic or inside the Kafka error handler?

Comment: This is Apache Kafka exception: better to ask the question with respective tag. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59398186/facing-org-apache-kafka-common-errors-invalidpidmappingexception-in-spring-kafka and here https://tgrez.github.io/posts/2019-04-13-kafka-transactions.html

Comment: Please show the stacktrace and what version of Kafka you are using